# Power pívot duda DATEADD

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

estoy intentando que una medida en power pívot ( usando CALCULATE y DATEADD) me da la eficiencia de la jornada anterior. El problema que tengo es con las fechas, ya que cada jornada no es consecutiva (osea no es cada 5 días por ejemplo). Cada jornada es cada 3 dias, en otro momento cada 5 días y así van alternando las fechas. ¿Como le puedo especificar a DATEADD que las fechas no son -3 o -5 días siempre sino que va variando?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Paul, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.

Comment: ¿De qué depende que sea "*la jornada anterior*"? ¿Es siempre la primera fecha previa existente en la tabla? ¿Es una única tabla? ¿Podrás mostrar un breve ejemplo de datos que estén en tu tabla? ¿La media sobre qué columna la querés calcular? ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora? ¿Podrás [edit] la pregunta agregando esta información?